# How can I use a field from class A as a parameter for a constructor in class B?

Tags: java, parameters

Question speaks for itself. This is what I have:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Stapel {
    public int stapel;
    private int maxZet;

    public Stapel() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        stapel = rand.nextInt(90) + 10;
        maxZet = stapel / 2;
    }

    public int getStapel() {
        return stapel;
    }

    public int getMaxZet() {
        return maxZet;
    }
}
```

Now, how do I use the public field above as a parameter in the following class? (where it says parameter)

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Computerspeler {

    public Computerspeler(parameter) {
    }

    public int zet() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int compZet = rand.nextInt(maxZet); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create an instance of `Stapel`, then pass the required field of this instance as parameter for the constructor of `Computerspeler`:

```
Stapel stapel = new Stapel();
Computerspeler computerspeler = new Computerspeler(stapel.getStapel());
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever we create an object of a class then the constructor of that class is called automatically..so in order to pass a public field of your stapel class just create an object of that class and then pass it

```
Stapel stapel = new Stapel();  //creating object of stapel class

Computerspeler computerspeler = new Computerspeler(stapel.getStapel());   // passing stapel object using getter of that field
```